# What is int(x) really doing?

Tags: coldfusion

I have the following code:

```
<cfloop list="1|1.2|1,2|1,2,3" delimiters="|" index="x">
    #X# - #int(x)# <br />
</cfloop>
```

Which produces this output:

```
1 - 1
1.2 - 1
1,2 - 40180
1,2,3 - 37623
```

What's happening when I pass in these lists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`INT()` Behavior is undefined if you pass it something that is not a number.

You can check if a string is numeric with the `isNumeric()` function.

If you need to extract an number from an arbitrary string, use [`parseInt()`](http://www.cflib.org/index.cfm?event=page.udfbyid&udfid=906).

Answer (score 3):

You'd better explain what results are expecting. Maybe you'll need `int(val(x))` as workaround.

Consider this loop example to see the differences between functions you can use:

```
<cfloop list="1|1.2|1,2|1,2,3" delimiters="|" index="x">
    #x# - #val(x)# - #int(val(x))# - #fix(val(x))# - #isNumeric(x)# - #isValid("integer", x)#<br />
</cfloop>
```

BTW, Railo makes this smarter: it throws an exeption when string can not be converted reliably (iterations 3 and 4).

Comment: I actually wasn't expecting any particular result, I just happened upon the behavior by chance and was trying to determine how the output was being generated.